# How can I speedup Firestore (or angularfire) when enablePersistence is active?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I created an example app on stackblitz.

Opening this url https://ionic-watdjp.stackblitz.io/ in the developer console, you see the following log line:
"Category {{name of category}} took:  {{load time is in ms}}"
for each of the 58 categories it will load.

With angularFire.enablePersistence() enabled:
- it takes ca 1 min to load all the categories

if I disable persistence it takes ca 4 seconds to load all the data.
You can try this modifying 1 line in app.module.ts using https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-watdjp

Is this difference expected?
Could I improve my data structure somehow to reduce the write time?

thanks
Federico

Comment: I am seeing 2 seconds to load all the categories.  It's possible you're running into a known performance problem where queries against a collection get slower the more cached data you have persisted for that collection.  So if over time you've done large queries and so you have lots of "extra" documents persisted, then the query could be much slower.  As a workaround you could manually clear the IndexedDB database (or just test in an incognito window to confirm it's fast there)